# Setting Sinatra app settings from config.ru

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

When I use Sinatra as Rack middleware I can do this in my Rackup file:

```
use MyGloriousApp.new do | le_app |
  le_app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
end
```

How do I accomplish the same when I need a `run` block at the end of the middleware
chain? Something like

```
run MyGloriousApp.new do | le_app |
  le_app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
end
```

Comment: `app = MyGloriousApp.new; app.settings.set :frobnicate, true; app.run!`
Not sure if this work, its just a idea.

Comment: Yep, that works - but like this:

    app = LeApp.new
    app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
    run app

If you hit that as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write it like these:

```
app = LeApp.new
app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
run app
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the precedence of the `do ...end` syntax when creating a block. Your example:

```
run MyGloriousApp.new do | le_app |
  le_app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
run(MyGloriousApp.new) do | le_app |
  le_app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
end
```

The block is passed to the `run` method, rather than your app’s constructor like you intend.

One way to fix this (which also illustrates what’s happening) would be to be explicitly associate the block with the constructor using parentheses:

```
run(MyGloriousApp.new do | le_app |
  le_app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
end)
```

The `{...}` syntax has a higher precedence than `do...end` and binds to the nearest method call to its left, so you could also do this:

```
run MyGloriousApp.new { | le_app |
  le_app.settings.set :frobnicate, true
}
```

In this case the block is associated with the call to `MyGloriousApp.new` rather than `run`.

The reason the `do...end` syntax works with the `use` method is that [`use` passes the block through to the middleware’s constructor](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb#L86). [`run` doesn’t do anything with any block passed](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb#L103-105), so it is just ignored.

Comment: @Julik I think the difference is because in the Rack DSL `use` expects a _class_ which it will then instantiate for you, passing it an app to use as the next stage as well as the parameters and block you provide. `run` expects an already initialized object.